# Select files that begins with the same four characters

Tags: batch-file, filenames, batch-processing

I'm learning to write batch files. I want to run qc.exe for files that begins with the same four characters.

For example in a folder, there are these files:

> APUZ123.120
>
> APUZ124.120
>
> APUZ125.120
>
> APUZ125.120
>
> BCIX123.120
>
> BCIX124.120
>
> DSET123.120
>
> DSET124.120

Some files begins with the same first 4 characters, like APUZ, BCIX, DSET.

How can I make the program selects all the files that have the APUZ characters only?

I know how to filter by their extension, like .12o, .txt:

```
for %%f in (.12o) do teqc +qc %%f
```

Or

```
for %%f in (APUZ123.120) do teqc +qc %%f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help you.

`for %%f in (APUZ*) do teqc +qc %%f`

`*` matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: Add a double quotes to the final "%%f" and then it's perfect. +1